# Add results of echoing array to another array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to add some additional things to an array but am getting lost somewhere along the line, I have the following code.....

```
<?php
    foreach ($search_values as $key => $value)
    {
    echo "'";
    echo $key;
    echo "'";
    echo " => ";
    echo "'";
    echo $value;
    echo "'";
    echo " , ";
    }
?>
```

Which produces the following....

```
'beds' => '2' ,
'property_type' => 'for-rent' ,
'zipcode' => 'se19' ,
```

I then have the following code that generates a map....

```
<?php
    if ( function_exists( 'pronamic_google_maps_mashup' ) ) {
    pronamic_google_maps_mashup(
    array(
    'post_type' => 'listings' ,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    )
    );
    }
?>
```

I need to somehow add the results of echoing the first array into this array, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to add the echoed results into the array -- you just need to add the array values onto the other array.  This can be done with [`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php);

```
pronamic_google_maps_mashup(
  // Merge your new array values with $search_values and the output of array_merge()
  // becomes the argument to panoramic_google_maps_mashup()...
  array_merge(array(
   'post_type' => 'listings' ,
   'posts_per_page' => -1
  ), $search_values)
);
```

Don't think of array contents in terms of how they print on the screen, as that will lead you down the wrong path. PHP has [many array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to accomplish all sorts of tasks.

To get a sense of what your final array will look like, debug it with `var_dump()`:

```
var_dump(
  array_merge(array(
       'post_type' => 'listings' ,
       'posts_per_page' => -1
      ), $search_values)
    )
);
```